# Div keeps wrapping when browser size shrinks

Tags: html, css

How do I stop a div from wrapping/moving below when the browse is resized to the left. everything else on the page stays still except this one box. I want it to not move and force the user to use the browser left right scroll to view it.

```
#signup_box {
    width: 363px;
    height: 392px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -34px;
    min-width: 363px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're floating it. It will wrap. Try positioning it manually, something like:

```
#signup_box {
    width: 363px;
    height: 392px;
    position:absolute;
    right:34px;
    top:0px;
    min-width: 363px;
}
```

Comment: that worked. i adjust the right and top to be right:584px; top:46px; its scrolling perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You have floated the div using `float: right;`, so it will adjust its position ("float") as necessary.

You can remove the `float` to stop this behavior, and ensure your page is wide enough to accomodate the width of this (and other relevant) elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`overflow: scroll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

No, There is a simple way to do this...It can work but it is css3. But you can try:

```
div {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Please reply if it works for you! Thanks! By the way, It will only work if you put it in all elements or just put it in a container. This way, you can put in float without it wrapping